# Can we change preview title and content in androidShareSheet?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to display text `Download this app` instead of `image` and change `Share with` text to `Recommend` one. Is it possible to change this?

[image]

**Something like this:**

[image]

```
private void share() {
        ...

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download this app");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Recommend");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Recommend"));

    }
```

Comment: "I want to display text Download this app instead of image" -- you would need to create an image that contains that text and use that for `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Comment: How about the title "Share with"? Is it changable?

Comment: I do not know, sorry.